# Fixing Branch Coverage Sonar issue

Tags: java, sonarqube

I am trying to run sonar and i take a sample of my code a  sampleClass to fix the branch coverage issue:

The issue was
**117 more branches need to be covered by unit tests to reach the minimum threshold of 65.0% branch coverage.**

I was trying to let my test cases cover many branches in the sample class.

but the number 117 cannot be changed after many trials.
What i have to do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 4):

You need to add more tests. For instance:

```
@Test
public void testThis(){
  if ( getBooleanA() || getBooleanB()){
    assertTrue(getBooleanA() != getBooleanB());
    }
  else{
    assertTrue(getBooleanA() == getBooleanB());
  }
}
```

here, you need to provide tests for the next cases:
 1. boolean A and B are both false
 2. boolean A and B are both true
 3. boolean A is true, and boolean B is false
 4. boolean A is false, and boolean B is true

if you miss one of those tests, there's a branch you haven't covered.

EDIT: it is clear (or it should be), that the assert in the else block is pointless, but I just added it, in case it didn't return a boolean, but an int, to show how easily it is to have a new branch that needs covering.

Comment: Many Thanks for your reply, i am already try to cover the branches but the number still 117 no progress. i don't know what was the issue.

Comment: The issue doesn't change. if you are using sonar (or something similar) it will point out where you are not covering all branches. just figure out which ones you haven't tested yet

Comment: writing three tests that test the same doesn't really add coverage, it's just testing the same. make sure the differences in all optional statements are checked